# dircolors/ls not being displayed correctly under NTFS drive

Tags: command-line, ntfs, colors, bashrc

I've been messing around with the colours of the files under the .dircolor file, and it worked perfectly under the Linux folders.

But whenever I try to ls to a NTFS folder all files are displayed under the green colour despite they are different type of files and of course different of the ones I set up in the .dircolor.

I've already searched the whole file with the colour number and got no clue...

Do I have to edit .bashrc or .dircolor to make them take into account those NTFS mounted drives?

Thanks for your time

Comment: are the the files maybe green because they are all recognized as executable, and the executable color is taking precedence over the coloring for filetypes?

Comment: The problem is that there are different kind of files, .mp3,.m4a,.jpg,.png all in the executable colour :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as mentioned by Paul was that all the files had executable permissions and as you can't permanently change permissions in a file inside a nfts drive it will remain always green

Comment: [NTFS is POSIX-compatible so you can store permissions if you mount it properly](https://askubuntu.com/a/74851/253474)

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue and I found solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=4779965

Note that on Ubuntu 12.04.1, you don't need to change your .bashrc (bash script already takes care of .dircolors file in home dir).

So just do:

```
> dircolors --print-database > ~/.dircolors
> vi ~/.dircolors
```

and change following lines:

```
STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE 01;34 # dir that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
OTHER_WRITABLE 01;34 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
```

Comment: The problem was that all were in the same color, it was probably that they all had executable permissions and as you can't change permissions in a nfts file it will remain always the same. Thanks anyway